# Swift comparison operator in function returning unexpected value

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm new to swift and coding in general and am having difficulty with getting the expected result from a comparator operator in a function.

I've made a simplified version of the issue I'm facing.
I have multiple buttons and I want to keep track of which one is selected by changing the value of 'count' to the number of that button. I want the background of the buttons to be green when selected to show that they are selected, however, I can't get it to work.

I am using a ternary operator in the '.background()' modifier which calls to a function. The function consistently returns 'false' regardless of what value 'count' is.
below the buttons I have written a more verbose way of doing this, which returns the correct bool value.

I can't figure out why the function is not returning the correct value.

```
struct storedValues {
    var count = 0
}

func checkTapped(_ val: Int) -> Bool {
    @State var values = storedValues()
    
    return values.count == val
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var values = storedValues()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            // Buttons to change value of count
            HStack{
                Text("Set count to 1")
                    .padding()
                    .onTapGesture {
                        values.count = 1
                    }
                    .background(checkTapped(1) ? .green : .gray)
                Text("Set count to 2")
                    .padding()
                    .onTapGesture {
                        values.count = 2
                    }
                    .background(checkTapped(2) ? .green : .gray)
            }
            
            // Expanded operation meant to be performed by checkTapped, works correctly
            if values.count == 1 {
                Text("Count = 1")
                    .background(.green)
            } else if values.count == 2 {
                Text("Count = 2")
                    .background(.green)
            } else {
                Text("Count != 1,2")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new `storedValues` instance inside your `checkTapped` function instead of comparing to the instance stored on your view.

Instead of doing that, simply declare `checkTapped` on `storedValues` and compare the `count` property against `val`. This will ensure that you are always checking the state stored on your view rather than creating a new temporary instance incorrectly.

Unrelated to your question, but type names in Swift should be UpperCamelCase, so you should rename `storedValues` to `StoredValues`.

```
struct StoredValues {
  var count = 0

  func checkTapped(_ val: Int) -> Bool {
    count == val
  }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var values = StoredValues()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            // Buttons to change value of count
            HStack{
                Text("Set count to 1")
                    .padding()
                    .onTapGesture {
                        values.count = 1
                    }
                    .background(values.checkTapped(1) ? .green : .gray)
                Text("Set count to 2")
                    .padding()
                    .onTapGesture {
                        values.count = 2
                    }
                    .background(values.checkTapped(2) ? .green : .gray)
            }

            // Expanded operation meant to be performed by checkTapped, works correctly
            if values.count == 1 {
                Text("Count = 1")
                    .background(.green)
            } else if values.count == 2 {
                Text("Count = 2")
                    .background(.green)
            } else {
                Text("Count != 1,2")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That solved my problem in the simplified project. Now that I've implemented the solution in my main project - where it is being called from within a view modifier (that is the only difference I can notice) -  it isn't working, I've posted details of that below.

Also appreciative of the convention tip about using UpperCamelCase for structs.

Comment: @Glorbothesupreme instead of posting your update as an answer, you should edit your original question with the updated code - also, you should show how how you are applying this `ViewModifier` to your View.